# How to download a view block as PDF in drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a page which contains a view block. This view generated block has yearly reports which can be filtered on basis of year (using exposed filter).

I would like to download the current filtered content of this block as PDF. 
How should i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Printer, email and PDF` module to output your view in a PDF: https://www.drupal.org/project/print

Related question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109654/printer-email-and-pdf-can-i-use-this-module-to-print-views